# What URL can I use to read older entries on a FeedBurner feed?

Tags: rss, feedburner

I am writing a small app that reads an RSS feed from feedburner.com - http://feeds.feedburner.com/org/ELCH

There is one entry posted every day. I can see a number of entries if I read the feed using Google Reader, but...

How can I retrieve previous entries via RSS?